# Design to block asynchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, blocking, nonblocking

```
var flow;

$.ajax({
    url: "qa/version.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( response ){ 
        flow = response.Version;
    }
});

$(".flow").append(flow);
```

Due to the nature of JS asynchronous design, the append would will be execute before it is being assigned a value in ajax call. What is the best way to tell the script to wait until flow gets assigned in ajax call, then do the append? I do not want to put append right below the success, I would like to keep them separate.

Comment: Place `$(".flow").append(flow);` inside of success funciton

Comment: Please explain *why* you want to keep the `success` callback and the `.append()` call separate. Doing so is the correct approach.

Comment: Also explain *why* there is a requirement for this to *wait until flow is assigned*.

Comment: Because I am not just assigning flow, say if I have 50 other parameters from json to get appended. I just think it's kinda messy, and I like to have all the appends in one place.

Comment: @TerryChen You can always reference a function by name there... you don't have to physically put the code there.  Alternatively, see my answer below for simply adding this as a handler for when the Deferred object is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

The "best way" is to perform the action in response to the asynchronous action:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "qa/version.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){ 
        $(".flow").append(response.Version);
    }
});
```

If you want to "keep them separate" then you can define a function to call in the response:

```
var appendFlow = function (flow) {
    $(".flow").append(flow);
};

$.ajax({
    url: "qa/version.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){ 
        appendFlow(response.Version);
    }
});
```

Separating the code into its own function is simply a matter of organizing your code into re-usable components.  Either way, by design the response can't be processed until it's received, so you'd perform your actions in response to the asynchronous call.

Answer (score 2):

Anything wrong with:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "qa/version.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function( response ){ 
    flow = response.Version;
    $(".flow").append(flow);
  }
});
```

Comment: He specifically says he doesn't want to do that... but who knows why.

Comment: Because I am not just assigning flow, say if I have 50 other parameters from json to get appended. I just think it's kinda messy, and I like to have all the appends in one place

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you don't want to put your success handler in the spot for a success handler, but here's an alternative that may help you.

jQuery returns a `Deferred` instance when you make AJAX requests.  You can use its `.done()` method to set up a callback later.

```
var dfd = $.ajax( /* your code here, without the success handler */);

// later on...
dfd.done(function (response) {
  $('.flow').append(response.Version);
});
```

See also:

- https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "qa/version.json",
    dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(response){
    $(".flow").append(response.Version);
});
```